# CiviCRM with Master - Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, webserver

I'm interested to get some latest war stories on CiviCRM with Master - Slave replication. Does it work well or are there any known issues? I've seen that Master - Master has some work needed but most comments about Master Slave have only needed minor configuration tweaks to work. Is this the case or have people had other issues?

Many thanks in advance